# Что означает эта запись?(указатель)

Tags: c++

```
const volatile char *port=(const volatile char*) 0x30;
```

Зачем мы в инициализации типа повторяем в скобках сам тип?и что означает присвоение указателю значения 0x30? разве так можно?где и как будет выделена память этому значению?

Comment: Преобразуем 0x30 в указатель и присваиваем указателю. Никакая память нигде не выделяется. Через этот указатель можно обратиться к памяти по адресу 0x30, ну, а что там, по этому адресу - это совсем другой вопрос...

Comment: Эти скобочки называются "явное приведение типа" или "каст" (cast). Без него компилятор ругался бы, что нельзя инициализировать указатель интом.

Comment: вполне может быть запрещенным адресом, ввиду  маленького значения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, скорее всего далее в коде будет использоваться в виде `port[base_addr] ...`, где base_addr это адрес конкретного блока регистров (портов) устройства на общей адресной шине. Т.е. это код из внутреностей ядра ОС или bare metal (т.е. программ, которые работают без ОС)

Comment: А почему если просто присвоить значение указателю без явного приведения будет ошибка?ведь мы так же запишем в значение указателя адрес куда ему ссылаться